# Why xqilla cannot find the namespace?

Tags: xpath, xquery, xmlstarlet, xidel, xqilla

This is failing and I'm not sure if it's a limitation or a bug of **xqilla**:

```
xqilla -i file.xml <(echo "//abcd:case[@xyz:displayName='locate']/abcd:condition/text()")
/dev/fd/63:1:3: error: No namespace for prefix 'abcd' [err:XPST0081]
```

However, I can get it to work with:

```
$ xqilla -i file.xml <(echo "//*:case[@*:displayName='locate']/*:condition/text()")

            hello world
```

Using **xidel** on the same file.xml:

```
$ xidel file.xml --extract '//abcd:case[@xyz:displayName="locate"]/abcd:condition/text()'
**** Retrieving: x.bpel ****
**** Processing: x.bpel ****
hello world
```

Using **xmlstarlet** on the same file.xml:

```
$ xml sel -t -v '//abcd:case[@xyz:displayName="locate"]/abcd:condition/text()' file.xml

            hello world
```

How do I make **sqilla** find the namespace?

**UPDATE:** I like to add, how I made it to work for **sqilla** below by creating another file:

```
$ cat newfile
declare namespace xyz="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/business-process/6.0.0/";
declare namespace abcd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/business-process/";
doc("file.xml")//abcd:case[@xyz:displayName='locate']/abcd:condition/text()
```

And then invoking it by:

```
$ xqilla newfile

            hello world
```

So is that how it is supposed to work for **sqilla**??

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for feature reviews, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because XQilla is very sensitive when it comes to namespaces - hence the initial error `[err:XPST0081]`. More command line info can be found at http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/CommandLine?show_comments=0 .